# How do I extend Kotlin Number class or use generics to create a simple property getter which will operate on all Number subclasses?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am trying to learn more about Kotlin abstract class extensions and generics by building very simple methods and property getters that extend built-in classes.  I've mostly been successful, but I'm stumped by the Number class.  My test property `Number.sgn` is intended to return the sign (1 or -1 as an Int) of any subclass of Number.  For simplicity, negatives should return -1, while positive numbers and 0 should return 1.  I'm not particularly interested in this method's use case, but for the understanding of how to write something simple like this -- and why my code generates the error it does.  The only import in my module is `kotlin.text.*` and the error message I receive does refer to a conflict there.  I'm just not understanding why it conflicts and how to overcome it -- although I'm guessing it's a novice error.

I first wrote the code to extend the Int class, which works fine:

`inline val Int.sgn get() = if (this<0) -1 else 1   // sign of number`

I then tried to generalize and move it to the Number class, like this:

`inline val Number.sgn get() = if (this<0) -1 else 1   // doesn't compile`

and the compile error is as follows:

`unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun String.compareTo(other: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Int defined in kotlin.text
inline fun Number.sgn() = if (this<0) -1 else 1
                                  ^`

I then tried a different approach, using generics:

`inline val <T:Number> T.sgn get() = if (this<0) -1 else 1`

and I received the same error from the compiler:

`error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun String.compareTo(other: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Int defined in kotlin.text
inline val <T:Number> T.sgn get() = if (this<0) -1 else 1
                                            ^`

Could anyone help me understand why there is a type mismatch, and why `kotlin.text` matters here?  Is there an approach that I could use to overcome this problem and get this property getter to apply to all subclasses of Number?  (Again, I know this isn't a meaningful use case, but rather a simplified example to help me understand the principles behind this.)  Thanks in advance for any advice anyone can give...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first function works because [`Int`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/index.html) implements `Comparable<Int>`, that's what the `<` operator is translated to. However, if you look at the [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/index.html) class, you'll see that it only has functions in it for conversions to its various subclasses - it doesn't implement `Comparable`, therefore, you can't use the `<` operator on it.

What you could do instead is convert your `Number` to a `Double` first, and then see if it's negative:

```
inline val <T : Number> T.sgn 
    get() = if (this.toDouble() < 0) -1 else 1
```

You could also make your original code (either with or without generics) work by implementing the `compareTo` function for `Number` as an extension:

```
operator fun Number.compareTo(other: Number) = this.toDouble().compareTo(other.toDouble())
```

Just be aware that casting everything to `Double` might result in losing precision.

Comment: Thanks for the quick/thorough answer.  Once you started me down the path of compareTo, I tried to research how to get Kotlin to just call the compareTo of the specific Number class in question rather than looking for an implementation of compareTo in Number.  I tweaked things until I ended up with:  `inline val <reified T> T.sgn where T:Number, T:Comparable<T> get() = if (this < (0 as T)) -1 else 1`  It works, but I'm still not sure I understand if I could have got there using generics without reifying T and/or whether reifying impacts performance materially.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even with the result of the same type.

```
inline val<T> T.sign where T: Number, T: Comparable<T> get() = run {
    if (this.toDouble() < 0) (-1 as T) else (1 as T)
}
```

More optimization in memory - convert source number to byte:

```
inline val<T> T.sign where T: Number, T: Comparable<T> get() = with(this.toByte()) {
    if (this < 0) -1 as T else if (this > 0) 1 as T else 0 as T
}
```